# Is there a mod that removes kingdomless lords?

Tags: mods, mount-and-blade-warband

After you take over every castle and town of a kingdom, often their lords (consisting of a party of 1) end up running around raiding all your villages by themselves.  This is annoying because they are super fast since they're by them selves and hard to catch.

Is there a mod that can either wipe out all lords of a kingdom once they lose their last piece of land or make it so you need a minimum number of men before you can raid a village?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kingdomless lords running around is no longer an issue as of the latest patch.  The lords of landless kingdoms will now defect at a much greater rate.